# Strange behavior of firefox and Chrome for JSP

Tags: html, css, spring-mvc

I have a strange issue that I am asked to make a Spring MVC simple application using many web technologies. Currently I am modifying this [Spring MVC Step-By-Step Tutorial part 2](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part2.html) at 2.2 I am asked to show the JSP using CSS style formatting. Ok I done it, but the problem is that when I am using the Firefox it does not show me the CSS formatting except the background color. But when I am using the chrome it shows me the CSS complete formatting.

```
    <html>
  <head>
  <style type="text/css">
  body{  
    background-color: #C1CDCD;
    background-image:url("logo.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right bottom;
    margin-right:200px;}

  h1{
    font-style:oblique;
    color:red;
    text-align:center;
    }

  p#p1
  {
    font-style:italic;
    font-family:"Times New Roman";
    font-size:18px;
  }

  p#p2
  {
    font-style:thick;
    font-family:"Times New Roman";
    font-size:18px;
  }
  .colortext_thick{
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:green;
  }  

  .italictext{
    font-style:italic;
  }
    </style>

  <title>Hello :: Spring Application</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World - Spring MVC Application</h1>
    <p id="p1" class="italictext">Greetings. This is also my first CSS type format example..</p>
    <p id="p2" class="colortext_thick">It is now <c:out value="${now}"/></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I couldn't figure out whats and where is the problem. First I thought I have a problem with code but when I access the same application on chrome, its seems very fine. Please help. Thank you

Edited: Below are the sample images of Firefox and Chrome running application
[image: Chrome] [image: Firefox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here,

```
background-image:url("logo.gif');
```

the opening and closing quote doesn't match. Firefox apparently stopped parsing CSS at that point.

Get them to match up:

```
background-image:url("logo.gif");
```

Comment: Thank you. It really worked. I have another question that in the same folder both jsp and the image is present. In IDE (Eclipse) the image is shown. But when I deploy to the tomcat it not shows the image. What the exact image path I have to use. I am sorry for disturbing you. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in 
`background: url("logo.gif');`
 You start with a double quote and end it with a single quote. Replace your body selector with this and it should work.

```
body {
  background: #C1CDCD;
  background: url("logo.gif");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:right bottom;
  margin-right:200px;
}
```